# Keshavan-Montanari-Oh matrix completion — clearing step

Tags: matrices, matrix-completion

I am trying to implement the algorithm for matrix completion proposed by [Keshavan, Montanari and Oh](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.3150v4) (2009). It consists of three steps:

1. *Trimming* which nulls some rows and columns to make the high singular values stand out
2. *Projecting* which basically does a SVD of a 'sparse' matrix
3. *Cleaning* which minimizes the residual errors

I have some problems understanding the *cleaning* step: *Projecting* gives you $U$, $\Sigma$ and $V$ (eq 3). Cleaning requires a $S$ matrix in $R(r,r)$ minimizing the cost function (eq 4). Optimizing the cost function with the Gradient Descent algorithm (below Remark 6.2) requires $S$. However, I cannot find any information how to calculate $S$. Can anybody please bring some light into how to understand these equations?

Comment: isn't $S$ just the $r\times r$ real matrix that minimizes the function defined in equation 5 from that paper?

Comment: Thanks Carlo! Just to clarify: Do you mean I have to find a new optimal S after each iteration in the Gradient Descent algorithm?